# How can I display a message when updates are made to an ng-list?

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, angularjs, client-side

I have a list of Questions displayed on a page, each Question has four Options to select from of which one is the answer.

Each Question has an "Update Options" link, so there are 10 Questions and there will be 10 Update Options buttons corresponding to each Question.

Once the user clicks on a particular "Update Question" button, I am able to update in the database through AngularJS two-way binding.

The issue I am facing is that I want to show a text block with "Successfully Updated" on top of the "Updated Question", but I am not able to do this.

Here is a [link to my jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/raghav_puthu/Nu7rZ/126/).

**HTML:**

```
<div ng-app>
  <div ng-controller="questionsController">        
    <div class="question row panel panel-default" data-ng-repeat="i in data">
        <div class="q-details panel-body">
            <div class="q-d-header row">
                <h4 class="col-md-4">{{ i.QuestionDescription }}</h4>
                <div class="q-actions">
                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" ng-click="updateQuestion($index);">Update Options</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="option">
                <div ng-show="updateQuestionMessage{{i.Id}}" class="message">saved</div>
                <ul class="o-content">

                    <li class="o-description" data-ng-repeat="o in i.Options">
                        <div class="o-d-text">{{ o.OptionDescription }}</div>
                        <div class="o-d-option">
                                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Is Right Answer:
                            <input type="radio" name="optionSelected{{o.Id}}" ng-model="o.IsAnswer" ng-value="true" />Yes
                            <input type="radio" name="optionSelected{{o.Id}}" ng-model="o.IsAnswer" ng-value="false" />No
                        </div>
                    </li>

                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <br/><br/>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

**ANGULAR SCRIPT**

```
    function questionsController($scope) {
    $scope.message = {};
    $scope.data = [
        {
            "QuestionDescription":"whats capital of Austrlia",
            "Id":1,
            "Options":[{'Id':1, 'OptionDescription':'Vic', 'IsAnswer':false},
                           {'Id':2, 'OptionDescription':'Canberra', 'IsAnswer':true},
                           {'Id':3, 'OptionDescription':'Sydney', 'IsAnswer':false},
                           {'Id':4, 'OptionDescription':'Brisbane', 'IsAnswer':false}]
    },
    {
         "QuestionDescription":"whats capital of America",
         "Id":1,
         "Options":[{'Id':5, 'OptionDescription':'New York', 'IsAnswer':false},
                {'Id':6, 'OptionDescription':'Washington', 'IsAnswer':true},
                {'Id':7, 'OptionDescription':'Houston', 'IsAnswer':false},
                {'Id':8, 'OptionDescription':'California', 'IsAnswer':false}]
    }]

    // update existing question
    $scope.updateQuestion = function (index) {
        $scope.updateQuestionMessage1 = true;
        $scope.message = "Options have been saved!";        
    };    
};
```

**THIS IS THE EXPECTED RESULT:**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

View change:

```
<div ng-show="i.Answered" class="message">saved</div>
```

Controller change:

```
$scope.updateQuestion = function (index) {
    $scope.data[index].Answered = true;
    $scope.message = "Options have been saved!";        
};
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/U44xZ/)